# Are datastore indexes same across multiple namespaces?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on developing a multi-tenant SaaS system and I'm storing all the data in Datastore. I have a separate namespace for every client, but the same set of "kinds" in all namespaces.

This is my question: If I build custom index for one entity kind, will this index be served across all namespaces? or should I specify the namespace also somewhere?

This is one of my custom indices:

```
- kind: loginTrack  
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: logDate
  - name: username
  - name: timeStamp
```

I deployed this as a custom index in Datastore, but I'm not sure if it works for all namespaces.

How does Datastore handle developer-supplied-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index itself, as you observed, has no room for namespace information, it operates the same way across all namespaces inside an app's domain.

What's different is the datastore partition mapped to each namespace. From [Multitenancy and partitioned data](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy#multitenancy_and_partitioned_data) (emphasis mine):

> Cloud Datastore uses partitions to silo data for each tenant. The
>   combination of a *project ID* and a namespace ID forms a partition ID,
>   which identifies each partition. An entity belongs to a single
>   partition, and **queries are scoped to a single partition**.

But note that operating on a certain tenant's data is your app's responsability: **all** operations related to a certain tenant **must** be executed in that tenant's partition/namespace context (i.e. the namespace must be specified as argument to the datastore-related calls).

For the particular case of using the (shared) index in a tenant's domain you have to specify the tenant's namespace when building the query. Otherwise you won't get the results from that tenant's partition.

Comment: So, if I run this query: `Query<Entity> query = Query.newGqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY, gql).setNamespace(organizationID)          .setBinding("program", programId).build();` Will my index be applied for all namespaces?

Comment: Nope, only to the one matching `OrganizationID`.

Comment: But I'm not declaring the namespace anywhere in the index file. The organizationID is from the user's session object. So, if I create an index, based on the session's organization, will the index will be applied for all namespaces?

Comment: The index *definition* and the index itself are not the same thing. The definition (i.e. what you configure) is the same/shared. But the index itself is (I suspect, I don't actually know the internal implementation) per namespace partition.