# How to configure namespace for composite index in Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a *kind* `events` that is stored in different *namespaces* which depends on service stage (*dev/stage/prod*).

I want to add composite index only for a kind in dev namespace but I can't find a way to configure it

I use command to create the index:

```
gcloud datastore indexes create ~/myapp/index.yaml
```

index.yaml

```
indexes:

- kind: events
  properties:
  - name: created
    direction: desc
  - name: approved
    direction: desc
```

Do you know a way to create an index only for one `namespace`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are datastore indexes same across multiple namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071038/are-datastore-indexes-same-across-multiple-namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite indexes are per database, and thus cross namespaces. There is no way to configure a composite index per namespace.

There is some other details in [Are datastore indexes same across multiple namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071038/are-datastore-indexes-same-across-multiple-namespaces) .